# `ng build` stays in terminal using `--extra-webpack-config`

Tags: webpack, cypress, code-coverage, ng-build

In package.json using below exits the terminal as expected.

```
ng build --progress=false --configuration production
```

Now, I want to instrument my code as well as exit terminal. However, using `--extra-webpack-config` in build the terminal is not closed.

```
ng build --extra-webpack-config=./cypress/coverage.webpack.ts --progress=false --configuration production
```

any additional parameter to close terminal?